# iPhone as Samba Server?

Tags: iphone, smb, ios

My aim here is to make my iPhone 4S (running iOS 5.0) serve its music library over SMB/Samba (Windows File Sharing protocol) so any computer on the LAN can access it.

Are there any iPhone apps available (for a non-jailbroken phone) that can act as a Samba file server for the iPhone's filesystem (or at least music library)?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box it's definitively not possible. To share music you need an Airplay capable counterpart (speakers etc.).
Also you can share music with iTunes.

Comment: I'd say it's far from impossible but likely to involve a jailbreak and software not available from the app store. Let's assume everyone here gets that the license agreement doesn't want us to modify the software - but that's not a reason to not discuss how or what jail breaking can do.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame it's only available via their proprietary AirPlay system. Sonos is the better and more popular as I see it, and I really want to use it with that for now.

Comment: You also can share music with iTunes

Comment: Also you can use third-party software to download all music from iPhone. Some of this software allows mount iPhone as drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are various examples on the Internet of the iPhone being turned into a server for basic content serving. The issue is that it's not multimedia, which is your request.

Jailbreaking is about the only way you can create a server to allow access on a per-file basis, but will only allow downloading of files, not streaming. There are various legit apps on the App Store that allow one to make the iPhone into network storage, but I've yet to experiment with media and streaming possibilities. Again, not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

FHub app for iPad will answer your questions (the version for iPhone will be available soon). Please check out at http://www.facebook.com/FHubApp